# How to separate variables in this equation: $\;y\frac{dy}{dx} = (x+7)(y^2+6)\;?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the differential equation $$y\frac{dy}{dx} = (x+7)(y^2+6)$$

I know that the first step is to isolate both term each side and then integrate...

But I can't figure out how to isolate term on this one, I would probably be able to solve the rest of the equation, just need to know how to start.

Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{y}{y^2+6}dy=(x+7)dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y \dfrac{dy}{dx} = (x+7)(y^2 + 6)$$

Divide both sides by $y^2 + 6$ to get $$\dfrac{y}{y^2+6}\,dy = (x+7)\,dx$$

Now, it's just a matter of integrating each side of the equation:

$$\int \dfrac{y}{y^2+6}\,dy = \int(x+7)\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks, that is what I first tought but I was not sure if I could simply throw the dx on the other side.. I'll accept when S/O let me.

Comment: Yes, you were on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$\frac{y}{y^2 + 6} \frac{dy}{dx} = (x + 7)$$

Now integrate both sides with respect to $x$ and you have

$$\int \frac{y}{y^2 + 6} dy = \int (x+7) \ dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(x+7)(y^2+6)\implies \dfrac{y}{y^2+6}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(x+7)\implies \dfrac{y}{y^2+6} dy=(x+7) dx\implies \int\frac{y}{y^2+6}dy=\int x+7 \,dx\implies \frac12\log|y^2+6|=\dfrac{x^2}2+7x\implies \log|y^2+6|=x^2+14x+c\implies y^2+6=e^{x^2+14x+c}\implies y=\sqrt{e^{x^2+14x+c}-6}$$